# suggest globally quasi-convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Can you suggest a function $f:R^2\to R, f\in C^2$, such that $f$ is globally quasi-convex (all its group sets are convex), but at no point convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$f(x_1,x_2)=-\exp(x_1)$$
is nowhere convex, but all sublevel sets $\{(x_1,x_2):f(x_1,x_2)\le c\}$ are convex (being half-planes).

Comment: Thanks. However is there a function that satisfies my constraints as well as $\frac{df}{dx} \ne 0$, $\frac{df}{dy} \ne 0$?

Comment: @SBM $f(x,y)=-\exp(x+y)$.